# Graph results not being rendered in APIview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, python-3.x

I have two templates that are working OK because the results are being displayed in console and one template renders the results as an APIView.

[image]

However, I want the results of this last template to be rendered with the Charts.js library that I have included. This is the code I have so far.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^tickets_per_day_no_results/$', ChartData8.as_view(), name="tickets_per_day_no_results"),
url(r'^tickets_per_day_results/$', ChartData8.as_view(), name="tickets_per_day_results"),
```

**Views.py**

```
class ChartData8(APIView):

def get(self,request):
    template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_no_results.html'
    form = DropDownMenuForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
    week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)
    # ....do stuff...
    data = { "label_number_days": label_number_days,
        "days_of_data": count_of_days,}

    return Response(data)
```

**Templates:** tickets_per_day_no_results.html and tickets_per_day_results.html

**tickets_per_days_no_results.html**: it just contains two drop-down menus to select year and week and a submit button with a post request. This template works fine.

```
<h3>Please, select the year and week number to retrieve the data.</h3>
<form id="search_dates" method="POST" action="/tickets_per_day_results/"> {% csrf_token %}
<h6>Select year</h6>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="select_year">
            <option value = {{form.year}}></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h6>Select week</h6>
        <select name="select_week">
            <option value= {{form.week}}></option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**tickets_per_days_results.html**: it contains the Charts.js libraries to render the results as graphs. Currently, this template display the results as an APIView.

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}

var endpoint = '/tickets_per_day_results/'

var days_of_data = []
var label_number_days = []

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken")},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        label_number_days = data.label_number_days
        days_of_data = data.days_of_data
        setChart()

    },
    error: function(jqXHR,error_data, errorThrown){
        console.log("error on data")
        console.log(error_data)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR))
        console.log("AJAX error: " + error_data + ' : ' + errorThrown)
    }
})

# This code generates the graphs with Charts.js
function setChart()
{
var ctx_tickets_per_day       = document.getElementById("tickets_per_day")

var tickets_per_day = new Chart(ctx_tickets_per_day, {
    showTooltips: false,
    type:'bar',
    data: {
        labels: label_number_days,
        datasets :
            [{
                label: 'User A',
                data: [days_of_data[0],days_of_data[1],days_of_data[2],days_of_data[3],days_of_data[4],days_of_data[5],days_of_data[6]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },
       {...rest of the code for generating graphs...}
{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}
<div class ='row'>
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint='{% url "tickets_per_day_results" %}'>
        <div>
            <canvas id="tickets_per_day" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
</script>
```

Which parameter should I change from my views.py or urls.py files to accomplish my result? I was able to get some charts but only when I used one view with a get method, not with two views.

[image]